# En Excel, ¿Se puede dejar un Label o Textbox en una posición fija?

Tags: excel, vba

¿Se puede dejar un Label o Textbox en una posición fija?, es decir, que no se desplace junto con el resto de la hoja; esto aparte de tener paneles inmobilizados.
La idea es dejar una especie de "ventana" que muestre subtotales, mientras el usuario se mueve por la hoja ingresando datos. La "ventana" estaría siempre visible y el usuario no tendría que desplazarse a la celda de los subtotales para ver "cómo va".

Answer (score 0):

Funciona de la forma que describes si bloqueas la primera fila y dentro de esa fila agregas tus controles:

[image: Porción del ejemplo de Excel]

Comment: En realidad la idea era no ocupar las filas inmobilizadas.
Pero gracias de todas formas, aparentemente es la única manera...